# Does NSNumber automatically cast strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumber, storekit

When creating an `SKStoreProductViewController`, I pass a dictionary with a parameter for the store identifier. :

```
@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @010101010 };
```

This value is supposed to be an `NSNumber` (as it is above):

> The value associated with this key is an instance of NSNumber, representing the iTunes identifier for the item you want the store to display when the view controller is presented.

But it works without complaint when I pass the value as a string:

```
@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"010101010" };
```

What's going on here? Is `NSNumber` automatically creating the correct number type from the string that it's given? Is this occurring in the `NSNumber` or is StoreKit doing this?

Comment: NSDictionary objects aren’t explicitly typed, so how would the dictionary know that the value is supposed to be a `NSNumber`? I think this must be a StoreKit behavior.

Comment: The only way this could work is if the store kit implementation is actually handling `NSNumber` and `NSString` objects.

Comment: Isn't that line creating an NSDictionary instance, therefore allowing either NSNumber OR NSString for the arguments?

Comment: Hmm... this is odd. The dictionary will accept any type against any key. The only problem may occur when StoreKit is actually trying to process the dictionary. Have you actually passed this to StoreKit to process?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yep, it gave me a product page with either a string or a number.

Comment: Is it possible behind the the scenes, `integerValue` is being called (or `floatValue`, etc) and this is just a coincidence? The example right below your quote says the iBooks id is `364709193`.

Comment: I can only guess that on the StoreKit side they are "doing their best" to process whatever is passed in. i.e. if you pass in a string that contains a valid number then it will convert it to an NSNumber first. Try passing in @"Apple" or something.

Comment: @MikeD +1 That's exactly what I was thinking about.

Comment: @Fogmeister That's very unlikely. Not impossible, but they don't tend to do that.

Comment: If I use `@"364709193 blah"` directly in the dictionary, it fails, but if i do `[NSNumber numberWithInt:[@"364709193 blah" intValue]]` it works.

Comment: You can mostly explain it by the receiver using `intValue` or `floatValue` or whatever to extract the numeric value.  And it's possible that the receiver is first doing a `description` call, which would explain the "blah" anomaly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, thinking about it...

Initially I thought they must be converting the `NSString` into an `NSNumber` before doing whatever they need to do to get the information you are looking for.

However, on second thought...

I would guess that `StoreKit` is using the `value` against `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` in a string. In which case they would do something like...

```
NSString *someStringToGetTheResults = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thisIsThePath...?storeKitID=%@", dictionary[SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier]];
```

This will be the same whether you pass in `@12345` or `@"12345"`.

Possibly...

No real way to tell though.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say that the value stored in the SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier key is supposed to be an NSNumber. Saving anything else in that key may work today, but may also stop working after any OS release, so don't do it.

As others have suggested, it's pretty likely that the store kit is fetching the value of the SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier key, assuming it's an NSNumber, and sending it an integerValue method to get it's numeric value. You got lucky since NSNumber and NSString both have an integerValue method.

Comment: Just another fun product of dynamic method resolution!